# Failed to make SIP calls (Asterisk + PhonerLite + Zoiper + Blink)

Tags: sip, asterisk

I've installed Asterisk PBX on a VirtualBox virtual machine, then created 3 phone extensions:

- 101 - PhonerLite,
- 102 - Zoiper,
- 103 - Blink

all of them are configured as "friends". All the clients are running on the same computer.

101 and 102 can call the "100" extension and hear automatic response from Asterisk.

101 can call 103 but when calling 102 it gets "503:Service Unavailable" message.

102 can call 101 and 103.

103 can't call any number, but can receive calls. It's dialing process goes through three phases: "Looking up destination...", "Connecting...", "Not acceptable here".

I closed all the clients except PhonerLite (101) on my PC and installed PhonerLite on another PC (102). Now I can call from 101 to 102 and in opposite direction.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox usually provide NAT'ed ip.

You have configure NAT and forward port 5060,10000-20000 udp.

For more info see

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Comment: Unfortunately, VirtualBox does not support port range forwarding. To Forward 10000 individual ports would be insane. So I stopped myself on bridged networking with dedicated IP-address. The question describes a situation with bridged networking.

Comment: Usually need only 5060.